# VBA change value ending to combobox value

Tags: vba, replace, combobox

I am trying to replace the last 3 symbols of a cell value with ones from my "LanguageBox" combobox for cells that values start with "UZL." and ends with ".ENG". All this happening in column E ("E2:E"&LastRow).

Can someone please share the code for this?

Workbook example:
https://easyupload.io/te2xll

Comment: It's hard to grasp what you intend to do

Comment: I Have many rows in column E range ("E2:E"&LastRow)  of which some start with "UZL." and end with ".ENG", for example "UZL.05.005.0.ENG" and I have a userform with 249 options to replace that "ENG" to, say "RUS". So I need to be able to change all such occurrences to the value from my combobox called "LanguageBox". You know?

Kinda like If Left "UZL." and Right ".ENG" replace to value from LanguageBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim s As String, sReplace As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set Ws = Sheets("BOM")
    
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("e2", .Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    vDB = rngDB
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        If s Like "UZL.*" And s Like "*.ENG" Then
            sReplace = Me.LanguageBox.Value '"RUS"
            s = Replace(s, "ENG", sReplace)
            vDB(i, 1) = s
        End If
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

Assuming that you have inserted a command button in your user form, insert it when you click the command button in the user form code. It can be implemented differently.

1. Userform image

---

[image]

2. Userform code image

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't do anything but returns an "object required" error. I attached a link to the workbook so you can see for yourself

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There might be a need to add .showalldata before running the code

Comment: @Mathew, Filter condition was not considered. It's a new problem.